# how can I get first iframe from string with many iframes

Tags: php

how I can get first iframe from string with several iframe tags? String contains only one or several iframe tags. 
For example:

```
$string = 
'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 0):

can it be done using explode function ?

```
$tag = explode("</iframe>",$string);
$first = $tag[0]."</iframe>";
```

maybe somthing like that

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<?PHP
  $htmlinput = <<<EOT
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
EOT;
?>

<?PHP
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($htmlinput);

  $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("iframe"); // DOMNodeList Object
  foreach($arr as $item) { // DOMElement Object

  }
?>
```